# Only play audio conv reply in SSML?

Tags: actions-on-google

I was wondering if it was possible to not include text in my SSML, since my audio file says 'Are you ready to play?', I dont need any speech from the google assistant itself.

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent',(conv) =>{

  const reply = `<speak>
  <audio src="intro.mp3"></audio>
   </speak>`;
  conv.ask(reply);

});
```

The code above produces an error since I do not have any text input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you probably got was something like

> expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[0].simple_response: 'display_text' must be set or 'ssml' must have a valid display rendering.

As it notes, there are conditions where the Assistant runs on a device with a display (such as your phone), and it should show a message that is substantively the same as what the audio plays.

You have a couple of options that are appropriate for these cases.

First, you can provide optional text inside the `<audio>` tag that will be shown, but not read out (unless the audio file couldn't be loaded for some reason).

```
<speak>
  <audio src="intro.mp3">Are you ready to play?</audio>
</speak>
```

Alternately, you can provide separate strings that represent the SSML version and the plain text version of what you're saying.

```
const ssml = `<speak><audio src="intro.mp3"></audio></speak>`;
const text = "Are you ready to play?";
conv.ask( new SimpleResponse({
  speech: ssml,
  text: text
}) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a hacky work around for this, By adding a very short string and then putting it in a prosody tag with a silent volume:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent',(conv) =>{
  const reply = `<speak>
  <audio src="intro.mp3"></audio>
  <prosody volume ="silent">a</prosody> </speak>`;
  conv.ask(reply);

});
```

This plays the audio and does not speak the 'a' text.

Comment: Yes, right but issue in google assistant because it's show in assistant.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to trick, try to use blank space to don't get **No Response error (... is not responding now)**

```
conv.ask(new SimpleResponse(" "))
const reply = `<speak>
  <audio src="intro.mp3"></audio>
   </speak>`;
conv.ask(reply);
```